# SASS not rendering in React / Webpack project

Tags: reactjs, sass, webpack

I added SASS to my project because I like using SASS for my CSS.  In my app folder I made CSS folder and a SCSS folder.  I run sass --watch scss:css to map over my scss changes to the css folder.  This is working great, I think.  In my webpack I added a loader to handle SCSS and SASS and added the files need to my package.json.  In order to start using the SASS styles do I need to include them in my index.html file or do I need to import them into each component I want to use them with the new es6 import x from 'xpath' thing?

Here are my package.json and webpack.config.js files

```
{
  "name": "newaccount",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "a form submission for new accounts",
  "main": "App.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "---",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.1",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.8",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.24.1",
    "node-sass": "^3.13.0",
    "sass": "^0.5.0",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path');


var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: __dirname + '/app/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
});

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './app/App.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public',
    filename: "index_bundle.js"
  },
  plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig],
  devServer: {
       inline:true,
       contentBase: './public',
       port: 3333
     },
  module: {
    loaders: [{ 
         test: /\.js$/, 
         exclude: /node_modules/, 
         loader: "babel-loader"
      }, {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          include: path.join(__dirname, "app"),
          loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
        },
        {
              test: /\.scss$/,
              loader: 'style!css!sass'
            }]
  }
};
```

My file structure is basically an app folder and a public folder.  Inside app you have components / containers / css / scss / utils and inside public is jus the bundle.js and index.html files.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using an external Sass command with Webpack. You need to put the Sass content in Webpack's dependency graph. To do this, tell Webpack you are using the files, which is done with `require()`. At the top of your Javascript file for the page needing the style, add

`require('./path/to/sass/scss')`

In development mode, this will turn your Sass code into Javascript that will inject the built CSS rules into the page. It's strange I know, but it gives you hot reloading of styles. You should also have a separate production build Webpack config using the ExtractTextPlugin to pull the built CSS out into a separate file, and load that file in your production HTML.

Further reading: [Webpack: When to Use and Why](http://blog.andrewray.me/webpack-when-to-use-and-why/).

Comment: So the entire scss application map to css is not needed?  I just write sass files and at the top of the react component .js file I want to use I include the sass file?  Like import sassBase from '../app/scss/base/_base.scss'   or just require('../app/scss/base/_base.scss')

Comment: Pretty good Webpack guide you made, didn't know bundling images as well.

Comment: Correct. Webpack should know about *all* your static assets that your app needs to run. It gives you the safety and guarantee that all files your app needs will load. Same way that calling `require()` on a Javascript file that doesn't exist will error and fail your build, now you get the same benefit for images,css,fonts,etc.

Comment: If I try to access the scss file directory from my component I get a pretty nasty error when building  ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./~/style-loader!./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./app/scss/base/_base.scss
Module build failed: 

^
      Invalid CSS after "...load the styles": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "var content = requi"
      in /Users/sam/Desktop/project/newAccount/app/scss/base/_base.scss (line 1, column 1)
 @ ./app/scss/base/_base.scss 4:14-263

Comment: Maybe I am still missing something because I am using SASS to break down into DIRs of base / components / layouts /mixins and then bringing those all together by importing into application.scss which is a file containing @import of 'base/index' etc - When I try to require the application.scss file in my react components everything breaks

Comment: Does your sass file you're requiring contain the code `var content=...` ? That's not valid sass

Comment: base looks like this 

.isRed {
 background: red;
}
which imports to _index.scss which looks like import 'var';
import 'base'; which imports to application.scss which looks like 

import 'main';
import 'base/index';
import 'mixins/index';
import 'layouts/index';
import 'components/index';

Comment: @ is in front of all the imports, but this comment box didn't like them so I removed them before posting

Comment: I think I figured it out - if you look at my webpack.config.js file you'll see its trying to load in style scss sass twice-  this caused a conflict

Answer (score 0):

My webpack.config.js file was loading scss and sass twice, changed it to

```
{
     test: /\.scss$/,
     loader: 'style!css!sass'
}]
```

by removing

```
{
     test: /\.scss$/,
     include: path.join(__dirname, "app"),
     loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
 },
```

Now I can include my SASS files in my react components.  Now I need to figure out how to access my images inside of my SASS files -  seems to toss mass errors =(

Comment: Images should be loaded the same way as requiring any file, with a local path, but use url instead of require. `background-image: url(./local/path.jpg)`